# Mapping an integer to an array

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary

I recently started with C++; I'm an hobby programmer, and I know a bit of Python.

I programmed a little snake. I wanted to insert another snake guided by the computer.

I decided to put the possible direction that the snake can take in an enum:

```
enum directions{UP, DOWN, RIGHT, LEFT, IN, OUT, FW, RW,NONE};

void fill_map(std::map<directions,V4> &map_vec);

void fill_map(std::map<int, directions*> &map_dir);

void fill_map(std::map<directions,directions> &map);
```

and map the enum for the needed function:

```
void fill_map(std::map<directions,V4> &map_vec){
    map_vec[UP] = V4(0,1,0,0);
    map_vec[DOWN] = V4(0,-1,0,0);
    //others

  }

 void fill_map(std::map<directions, directions> &map){
    map[UP]= DOWN;
    map[DOWN]= UP;
    //others
  }


void fill_map_axis(std::map<int, directions*> &map_dir){
    directions array_x[2] = {RIGHT,LEFT};
    map_dir[0] = array_x;

    directions array_y[2] = {UP,DOWN};//store the array
    map_dir[1] = array_y;

    directions array_z[2] = {FW,RW};//store the array
    map_dir[2] = array_z;

    directions array_w[2] = {IN,OUT};//store the array
    map_dir[3] = array_w;

}
```

The fill_map functions are called in the snake constructor.
Basically what I wanted to do in the fill_map_axis is to map an integer corresponding to the index of the coordinate (0 coord x, 1 coord y etc) and map the two directions that move along those axis.
So I stored an array of two directions.

Now I call the function:

```
directions SnakeCPU::find_dir(V4 point){
    //point is the target point
    directions dir;
    int index = get_coord_index(point); //get the index where to move
    double diff = head_pos[index]-point[index]; //find the difference between the head and the target point

    directions* axis = dir_coords[index]; //call the map containing the directions stored in an array.

    if(diff<0.){

        dir = *axis; //use the first
    }
    else if(diff>0.) {
        axis++;
        dir = *axis; //use the second
    }
    else{
        dir = NONE;
    }

    return dir;
}
```

Although the map are initialized in the Snake constructor, it seems that the returned value from the pointer axis is a random memory block.

So my question: do you see a mistake in the code? did I used the pointer axis with sense?

I'm really not expert with pointer; in Python the map is instantiated with a dictionary like this:

```
dir_coords = {0:[LEFT,RIGHT], ...}
```

so I just need to call it:

```
axis = dir_coords[index]
dir = axis[0]
#or
dir = axis[1]
```

edit:

Snake constructor:

```
Snake::Snake()
{    
    fill_map(dir_vectors);
    fill_map(dir_coords);
    fill_map(opposite_dir);
    head_pos = V4(0.,0.,0.,0.);
    //other stuff...
}
```

Comment: Your `array_x` etc. are **local variables**, and you are only inserting a pointer to those arrays. After the function scope exits, those pointers are no longer valid. In short, everything is udders up. I recommend storing a `std::pair<direction, direction>` in your map.

Comment: Where is the code for the SnakeCPU constructor?

Comment: What are `head_pos[] and point[]`? Also, `axis++; dir = *axis;` can be replaced with `dir = '*(++axis);`

Comment: @Kerrek, make that an answer.

Comment: I thought, good :D what is a std::pair? and I call it like pair[0] and pair[1]?

Comment: @Moo: I'm tired, I really didn't want to... this requires plenty of writing, and I don't know if the OP is interested in a largish redesign...

Comment: I'm interested in a redesign ;) any comment is appreciated! I want to learn! Thx for the help anyway!

Comment: @Pella86: Pairs are accessed as `x.first` and `x.second`. Apart from being very handy in their own right, pairs are also ubiquitous when you deal with maps, so I hope you'll learn to love them soon ;-)

Comment: I'm already appreciating them ;) thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a shot in the blue, here is how I would design this.

```
#include <map>

enum EDirection { NONE = 0, UP, DOWN, RIGHT, LEFT, IN, OUT, FW, RW };

typedef std::map<EDirection, V4>           DirectionMap;
typedef std::pair<EDirection, EDirection> DirectionPair;
typedef std::map<int, DirectionPair>            PairMap;

extern const DirectionMap map_vec {
  { UP,   (0, 1, 0, 0) },
  { DOWN, (0,-1, 0, 0) },
  // ...
};   // using C++11 initialization lists for convenience

extern const PairMap map_dir {
  { 0, { RIGHT, LEFT } },
  { 1, { UP, DOWN }    },
  // ...
};
```

Here I decided to make `map_vec` and `map_dir` global constants, because I gathered that that's essentially what they are. To initialize those, I rely on the new C++11 initialization syntax. If that's not an option, we can also fill the map in the traditional way:

```
PairMap map_dir;
map_dir.insert(std::make_pair(0, DirectionPair(RIGHT, LEFT)));
map_dir.insert(std::make_pair(1, DirectionPair(UP, DOWN)));
// ...

DirectionMap map_vec;
map_vec.insert(std::make_pair(UP,   V4(0, 1, 0, 0)));
map_vec.insert(std::make_pair(DOWN, V4(0,-1, 0, 0)));
// ...
```

(Yes, you can also write `map_dir[0] = DirectionPair(RIGHT, LEFT)'`. I don't like the square brackets, though, they feel too violent for my taste.)

Comment: I like the form map["key"]=value is like python ;) and thx again for  the help!

Comment: @Pella86: no problem. Let me know if you have any problems with those constructions :-) The square brackets are non-const and cause elements to be inserted if they're missing, so I feel reluctant to use those, but of course here we *want* to create elements, so I'm overly panicked for no reason.

Comment: good to know I didn't thought about the possible drawback! but anyway the problem is solved (now the cpu snake is faster than me... and damn it I'm loosing like every round...)

Answer (score 0):

As Kerrek said, you filled map_dir with *automatic* scoped variables, which means they are automatically destroyed when the function ended.

```
void fill_map_axis(std::map<int, directions*> &map_dir){
    //This variable will be destroyed when the function ends
    directions array_x[2] = {RIGHT,LEFT};  
    map_dir[0] = array_x; //should have a warning at least, probably not compile
```

What you probably want is *actual* directions in the map

```
void fill_map_axis(std::map<int, std::pair<directions, directions> > &map_dir){
    //This variable will be destroyed when the function ends
    std::pair<directions, directions> array_x = {RIGHT,LEFT};  
    map_dir[0] = array_x; //makes a copy
```

Comment: That last assignment doesn't seem to make sense: `array_x` is an array, not a `directions`.

Comment: yup.  I kept thinking it was a pointer to a single directions, and partially coded as such.